# Вопрос про cookie

Tags: php, cookie

Это только у меня не работает? Или у вас тоже?

```
<?
if(!isset($_COOKIE['name'])) {
    setcookie ('name','server');
}
?>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Куки</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <? echo "HELLO! ".$_COOKIE['name']; ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Я уже ничего не могу понять. Вчера на главном сайте пошло, скопировал код, вставил на другую страничку - и аврал! Не работает. Сегодня решил просто протестить на чистом листе, так сказать, с нулевой странички. И не идет! Может, поправите меня, может, что делаю не так?

**Обновление**

Пробелов нет. Он стоит в самом верхнем угле. Код отформатировал, тег `<?php` поставил. Но всеравно та же ошибка. Если у Вас работает, то значит у меня что-то не так

Прошу тогда помочь разобрать действия пошагово. От начала выполнения скрипта. Я просто не пойму что за заголовки отправляются? Куда они отправляються? Раньше я работал с обычными формулами в экселе, так вот там была такая штука - проверка формулы пошагово. А здесь есть что-то подобное? Если есть дайте ссылку на программу, которая это делает, может она мне поможет разобраться какие заголовки у меня посылаются раньше кода?

Comment: Здесь, вроде, все правильно. Возможно, где-то перед пхп кодом есть пробелы, возможно, у вас выключена директива short_open_tag. Открывайте пхп код тегом <?php , а не <?

P.S. Отформатируйте код.

Comment: @zaryad68gmail, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора. В коде, не использующиеся и не несущие смысла фрагменты тоже лучше убирать.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: @zaryad68gmail, залейте куда-нибудь ВЕСЬ ваш код и покажите нам. Этого кусочечка недостаточно для выявления проблемы. И еще, попробуйте так, хотя это погоды не изменит: 

>><?php echo isset($_COOKIE['name']) ? "HELLO! ".$_COOKIE['name'] : ''; ?>

Comment: @mountpoint, это проверочный код, он есть весь. У меня выпадает сразу ошибка, и куки не устанавливаются. Код ошибки загружаю на файлообменник:
http://www.ex.ua/557818683047

Comment: итить калатить, сколько шума из-за бума

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильное поведение приложения и ошибки тоже приводите, желательно дословно, а то мы же не знаем ничего о них. Помимо описания ошибки, типа

> Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by ...

В них обычно точно указано место возникновения ошибки и прочая важная информация. Также проверьте кодировку файла, мало ли там установлен какой-нибудь "`UTF-8 с BOM`", который все портит (при работе в notepad наблюдается).

Comment: @Alex Krass, Спасибо оказалось "UTF-8 с BOM". Впредь буду повнимательнее

Answer (score 0):

Дело в том, что $_COOKIE['name'] **не будет** существовать сразу после setcookie ('name','server');
А при следующей перезагрузке страницы - будет

Comment: Я думаю, автор это учел и обновлял несколько раз страничку. Хотя, кто знает...

Comment: Я знаю это, но он не устанавливается, так как выдает ошибку